# What are the advantages of using a WPF DevExpress LayoutControl give me over a WPF StackPanel?

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I'm looking at the WPF DevExpress LayoutoutControl vs WPF standard StackPanel.
They both look pretty similar in the functionality they provide.
Can someone explain to me the basic differences?

What additional functionality/features does using the LayoutControl buy me?

Is a WPF 's functionality closer to that of a LayoutControl?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DevExpress `LayoutControl` allows you to arrange items as tabs or in groups of different directions. Please refer to the [docs](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/8147/controls-and-libraries/layout-management/tile-and-layout/layout-and-data-layout-controls/layout-control) for examples and more information about the control.

The built-in `StackPanel` simply arranges items into a single line that can be oriented either horizontally or vertically.

It has no concept of groups, tabs or customization modes and it doesn't support automatic alignment or resizing of child controls.

Comment: Additionally, the DevExpress control will support their themeing/skinning mechanism.